# Fixed sbyte[] to string C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, structlayout

I'm trying to get a string from memory using `StrucLayout` and `FieldOffset`

But I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how `byte` works.

Here is my code ATM :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct InfoDetails
{
    [FieldOffset(0x14)]
    public fixed sbyte Name[50];

    public string getName
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (sbyte* namePtr = Name)
            {
                return new string(namePtr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code `returns` : `T`. Expected result is `TEZ`.

Any advices on why I'm doing it wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the memory layout?

Comment: Why do you use `sbyte` and not unsigned `byte`? And to convert `byte[]` to string use `Encoding` class.

Comment: Perhaps `Name` is unicode (so two bytes/character), while the `string(sbyte*)` expects one byte/character.

Comment: ok, you know how strings are stored? as far as I understand, they are stored by 2byte values (char). new string() has 8 overloads: one of them is  a pointer to a byte array terminated with 0x00. So you get only the first byte

Comment: give char a try

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody ! I've posted a working solution. Don't really know it it's the best one but it works for now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the signature to:

```
[FieldOffset(0x14)]
public fixed char Name[25];

public string getName
{
    get
    {
        fixed (char* namePtr = Name)
        {
            return new string(namePtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I changed `sbyte` to `char` and I halved the size of the buffer (because `sizeof(char)` == 2)

Or you could even, more simply add a single cast to `char*`:

```
fixed (sbyte* namePtr = Name)
{
    return new string((char*)namePtr);
}
```

without changing anything else.

Comment: Solution number one is giving "T". But solution number 2 is working perfectly and seems a lot better ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem with string encoding. Consider the following test code:

```
unsafe
{
    InfoDetails d;
    var encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    var stringBytes = encoding.GetBytes("TEZ");
    for(int i=0; i<stringBytes.Length; i++) d.Name[i] = (sbyte)stringBytes[i];
    Console.WriteLine(d.getName);
}
```

You will get indeed "T", but if you change the encoding to `Encoding.ASCII` you get "TEZ" as expected.

Solution: you need to know the encoding of the information beforehand, and generate the string accordingly. Looks like it's Unicode, so try this first:

```
fixed (sbyte* namePtr = Name)
{
  return new string(namePtr, 0, 50, Encoding.Unicode);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, it's a lot better than what I had before but it gets me : "TEZ\0\0\0ꃀб\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0002\026\0\0\0\0䕀⚣\0"

I've posted a solution that is working for now, I will try to improve it later !

Comment: That's weird. What are the exact bytes you are getting?

Comment: @Cesar that means your `Name[50]` declaration is not really correct. It assumes string is of fixed size of 50 bytes, but in this case string is much smaller, and the rest of those 50 bytes are not even all zeros but some garbage, which means they probably belong to something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answer, they helped me to get a working solution. I don't really know if it's the best one :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public unsafe struct InfoDetails
    {
        [FieldOffset(0x14)]
        public fixed byte Name[50];

        public string test
        {
            get
            {
                List<byte> clearBytes = new List<byte>();
                fixed (byte* namePtr = Name)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        if (namePtr[i] == 0x0 && namePtr[i + 1] == 0x0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        clearBytes.Add(namePtr[i]);
                    }
                    if (clearBytes.Count() % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        clearBytes.Add(0x00);
                    }
                    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(clearBytes.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think your solution is overcomplicated, plus manually dealing with string encodings is usually not a good idea. Isn't `new string(namePtr, 0, 50, Encoding.Unicode)` working for you?

Comment: @Konamiman You are compleetly right about the overcomplicated but your solution is leading to this : "TEZ\0\0\0ꃀб\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0002\026\0\0\0\0䕀⚣\0"